# Quantify variables from a selected column

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to quantify the variables for a very large matrix.
For example, let's say I have

```
1 Blue
2 Blue
3 Blue
4 Red
5 Red
6 Yellow
```

And I would like to obtain:

```
1-3 Blue
4-5 Red
6-6 Yellow
```

Is that possible using awk?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$2!=p{if (s) print s"-"e, p; s=$1} {e=$1; p=$2} END{print s"-"e, p}' file
1-3 Blue
4-5 Red
6-6 Yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

an alternative which doesn't require sorted or grouped input

```
f() { sort -k2 -k1,1n$1 "$2"; }; paste <(f "" file) <(f "r" file) | 
awk '!a[$2]++{print $1"-"$3,$2}'

1-3 Blue
4-5 Red
6-6 Yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
{ 
    if(min[$2]=="" || $1<min[$2]) # compare for min
        min[$2]=$1
    if(max[$2]=="" || $1>max[$2]) # compare for max
        max[$2]=$1
}
END {
    for(i in min)                 # output loop
        print min[i] "-" max[i], i
}' foo
```

Output:

```
4-5 Red
1-3 Blue
6-6 Yellow
```

Output order is random. Pipe it to `sort` for ordered output.